# Computer Vision application(+web interface) for face detection and recognition from database

Tags: java, php, mysql, opencv

My project is a computer vision java application which should implement the following :

1. A web interface through which the  form entry+images(for example a student data) will be stored into a database(Mysql) & images into directory common to my java application.
2. Then the  data & images can be retrieved from my java Gui application and I can perform  the following operations of image  processing through OpenCV.
3. Actually,I want to run the face detection on images retrieved and discard the false entries(no proper face).
4. Also the application user/admin can search an image based on text search(By Id) or By another reference image using face recognition.

I am well familiar with Java but the problem is that I need a guidance on how to organise it in a stepwise manner(links appreciated).OpenCv,Php and mySql are really messy.I know doing the openCV stuff within java is real overhead but i really want to do it.But If there is any suggestion to do it elseway please guide me.So any kind of help is a ray of hope for me.

- Thanks.

Comment: Avoid all overheads. You can add them later once the minimal functionality is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a nice application. Here is what I would suggest you:

> 1- A web interface through which the form entry+images(for example a student data) will be stored into a database(Mysql) & images into directory common to my java application.

You will be able to easily create such application with Php and Mysql, just look for some tutorials on image uploading and php.

> 2- Then the data & images can be retrieved from my java Gui application and I can perform the following operations of image processing through OpenCV.

I'd recomend you using JavaCV. It is a wrapper over OpenCV which seems to work very well from some tests I have made. You get the flexibility of Java and the performance of C++ through a native bridge.

> 3- Actually,I want to run the face detection on images retrieved and discard the false entries(no proper face).

You can easily adapt the OpenCV face detection code to JavaCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

> 4- Also the application user/admin can search an image based on text search(By Id) or By another reference image using face recognition.

The search by id is easily accomplished through some JPA or even JDBC connection. Now the similar face search is tricky. I'd point you to this link http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html about face recognition in OpenCV.

I hope that helps.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Hi Kush, you are welcome! Can you choose this as the accepted answer if you want, please? Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

Here how it can go as far as I can suggest though will need to take care of issue that might not be addressed here.

- You will be creating a webservice that will be accessed directly for to upload images. The  same service can be used to download the images from your Java application. So make sure you have created a well defined service that takes care of these two distinct operations and are cleanly exposed to the outside world. MySQL will be the back end DB that shall take care of storing either student info and/or images themselves. You can write a service without MySQL and just have the service store images and/or student info locally (at the server end) and later on you can develop code to integrate MySQL. [A good and simple link to MySQL and Php](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)
- [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) Would be the candidate for your java application. You will leverage the power of OpenCV easily. Develop the application and test it against your service. Try just downloading some image from the service first. If that works, go on to Image processing part.
- Make sure you undetstand Face Detection and Recognition. These are two different things. From the OpenCV wiki [FaceDetection](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection&ei=2ZhyT6S-McHjrAesn8juDQ&usg=AFQjCNHVPuGmHjNXHkU2t2dIRqgBlzkRGg&sig2=olzRpmU3kjeyGPLttEgdZQ) and [FaceRecognition](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition&ei=2ZhyT6S-McHjrAesn8juDQ&usg=AFQjCNHXYO0ZL9OuHp2p5M0ew_rpyDlHqQ&sig2=e4Qq8tj6vvA0e30dU5wG1w)
- Searching via id/text string would be trivial if you get through step one and understand querying data. Searching via image would me you would store the face recognition artifact (vectors,dimensions,eigen values etc..whatever). Once store on your server, your application will then send off a input image artifact to your server where matching will be done and result returned.

**

> To summarize

**

- Connecting your webservice and MySQL via connectors such as JDBC. This is very important. No SQL connection, means no DB and a useless service.
- Service taking care of student info upload/download.
- Image processing. Face artifacts calculation must be common. Same code can run at server and client (makes sense, doesn't it?).
- Querying for search either by string or image. Two different types of searches. Client must tell what type of search the server should do.